# How we can detect that MS Excel is installed in Silverlight 4 and C#

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

How we can detect that **MS Excel** is installed in **Silverlight 4** and **C#** ?

Can I use somehow this code or ??

```
  dynamic excelApp;
  excelApp = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
  if (excelApp != null)
   {
      // MS Excel is installed!
   }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this registry path:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\InstallRoot::Path
```

Replace 12.0 (for Office 2007) with the corresponding version number:

```
Office 2000 -  9.0
Office XP   - 10.0
Office 2003 - 11.0
Office 2007 - 12.0
Office 2010 - 14.0
```

check [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/orkXP/HA011364611033.aspx) for more info.